# Position of fingers for better productivity in Vim

Tags: vim, touch-typing

I am an absolute starter with `vim`. Right now I am learning vim through `vimtutor`. To get better productivity where should my fingers be placed while using H,J,K, L keys . Any diagram will suffice here . I want to learn it correctly the first time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should hold Your fingers on home row.

[image]

Vim key positioning try to take advantage of this and positions commonly used functionalities around home row. By doing this you can quickly switch between navigation and edition.

Comment: Don't you feel that HJKL encourages shifting the base position of the right hand one key to the left?

Comment: No, I would suggest to use jk for up/down and use e/b/f for moving left right. It is faster.

Comment: I agree with De Moon, you should keep your keys on the homerow and when you need to move your hand left a bit or use `e/b/f`, it is much faster and you don't have to learn/de-learn/re-learn anything because of a shift.

Comment: I have always pressed the H with my forefinger, as well the J. Works pretty well, and is more intuitive than shifting to the right or using e/b/f, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn [touch typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing).
There are lots of tutorials out there.

Once you do this you will be much more productive, not only with vim but with any other application which requires typing as well.